# Transactions in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode

How do I see the transaction history of my chaincode in Hyperledger Fabric? Like in ethereum we can see how much gas is spent on each transaction on the console itself i.e., below the smart contract.

Answer (score 0):

Using the SDK, you have the `Channel` class available: https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/release-1.4/Channel.html#queryTransaction__anchor.

If you are asking about a higher level tool, you have Hyperledger Explorer available: https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer.